# Angular sanitize problems with umlauts

Tags: angular, sanitization, html-sanitizing

i'm sanitizing a sting `Gerät aktualisieren` with

DomSanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, value)

```
Ger&#228;t aktualisieren
```

but why? I would like to keep umlauts and sanitize

Comment: Have you solved it?

Comment: sorry, not solved yet